What does print(*sorted(map(int, a ^ b)), sep='\n') mean?
Problem statement:

Input Format

The first line of input contains an integer,m .
The second line contains m space-separated integers.
The third line contains an integer, n.
The fourth line contains n space-separated integers.

Output Format

Output the symmetric difference integers in ascending order, one per line.


I did not understand this part print(*sorted(map(int,a^b))
here a and b are sets
This is the code:
_, a, _, b = input(), set(input().split()), input(), set(input().split())
print(*sorted(map(int, a ^ b)), sep='\n')


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site for specific questions, so which part specifically don't you understand? For example, I assume you know what print() does, right? Then ignore that and just focus on what you don't understand. For more tips, see [ask]. You can [edit] to clarify.

Er, maybe you don't know what print(*x) does, which is fair. There's an existing question about that.

Admittedly, this is rather compact Python code, and not very suitable for beginners to read (or even learn). So, depending on your existing Python knowledge: are there any specific things in that line you don't understand?

I have an issue with this question.  You forgot to actually ask one!

So, it looks like this is an assignment or coding challenge. Where does the code shown come from? Is it a solution given by your instructor or another entrant? Have you written your own version, and don't understand how and why they differ? Context would help clarify the issue here.

@9769953 This code isn't suitable for anyone, except maybe code golfers.

@MarkRansom The question was in the title, and the text narrowed it down.

@Barmar mostly I just wanted to register my annoyance at the title.

@MarkRansom Passive-aggressive comments on the Internet are practically never understood by the person they're targeted at.

Here's a more specific question about print(*x) I just cleaned up

@chepner Why? Looks straightforward and fine to me (except I might prefer key=int over map).

@Barmar oh I agree.  But I really was having trouble extracting a question, I'm glad someone figured it out and presented a well written answer.

@nocomment code is going to be read 10 times more than it is going to be written.  Better to emphasize understandability over terseness.

@MarkRansom Hmm? It is very easy to understand. Easier than the answer's obfuscated version.

@nocomment Either x = a, b, c or x, y, z = a. I don't think I've ever seen a series of ordinary assignments x = a; b = y; c = z that became more readable by trying to combine them into a single assignment that both creates and immediately unpacks a tuple like x, y, z = a, b, c. Combing that with effectual code like I/O and post-processing of the actual inputs makes it worse.

Similarly, an ordinary for loop like for x in sorted(map, ...): print(x) is much more readable.

@chepner Oh you mean the first line, not the one the question is about. Yeah I'd prefer that in four lines, without assigning the first and third. But I think their way is ok, too. I disagree about the print/loop, both are about equally good and their way has the advantage of being easier to adjust when the problem setter realizes their inconsistency and changes the output spec to one line of space-separated ints like the input spec.


I did not understand this part print(*sorted(map(int,a^b)) here a and b are sets

Breaking it down operation by operation:
c = a ^ b  # Items in a or b but not both
d = map(int, c)  # Call "int()" on each item in c (returns an iterator)
e = sorted(d)  # Return a new list by sorting the input iterable

print(*e, sep='\n')  # Unpack the list "e" into separate args for the
                     # print function and separate them with newlines.
                     # This is basically the same as:
                     # >>> for x in e:
                     # >>>     print(x)

Thank you.if suppose a and b are of type string ,example,a='10' b='9' then if we perform print (a ^ b) why do we get error but the above code works fine without errors even though sets contain string elements

the ^ operation is undefined for strings. what do you think the result of "hello" ^ "world" should be? It has not been defined by the creators of python. It has been defined for sets as the symmetric difference. Creating a set from a string simply creates a set from the letters in the string, so the same example using sets would look like: set("hello") ^ set("world") returns {'d', 'w', 'e', 'h', 'r'}

@Aaron the question makes it clear that a and b are both sets, and looking at the code you can see the set members will be strings not characters.  The output of .split() is a list of strings, not a single string.  Your comment seems irrelevant.

@MarkRansom my comment is responding to the prior comment by the author, and is not regarding the original question.

Sorry for the misunderstanding.
